# A Study on the Modification of PDF in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf

**Project Environment**

The environment we are currently developing is using Windows 10. nodejs 10.16.0, express web framework. The actual environment being deployed is the Linux Ubuntu server and the rest is the same.

**What technology do you want to implement?**

The technology that I want to implement is the information that I entered when I joined the membership. For example, I want to automatically put it in the input text box using my name, age, address, phone number, etc. so that the user only needs to fill in the remaining information in the PDF. (PDF is on some of the webpages.)

If all the information is entered, the PDF is saved and the document is sent to another vendor, which is the end.

**Current Problems**

We looked at about four days for PDFs, and we tried to create PDFs when we implemented the outline, structure, and code, just like it was on this site at https://web.archive.org/web/20141010035745/http://gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF

However, most PDFs seem to be compressed into flatDecode rather than this simple. So I also looked at [Data extraction from /Filter /FlateDecode PDF stream in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731425/data-extraction-from-filter-flatedecode-pdf-stream-in-php) and tried to decompress it using QPDF.

Unzip it for now.Well, I thought it would be easy to find out the difference compared to the PDF without Kim after putting it in the first name.
However, there is too much difference even though only three characters are added... And the PDF structure itself is more difficult and complex to proceed with.

Note : https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf (PDF official document in English)

Is there a way to solve the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a PDF from scratch and possibly extract data from it and you are finding this a more difficult prospect than you first imagined.

Check out my answer here on why PDF creation and reading is non-trivial and why you should reach for a tool you help you do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53357682/1669243

Comment: Indeed, the gnu introduction to pdf gives first hints to understand what one sees when opening a pdf in a text viewer, and you probably can create minimal pdfs with it. But for serious use cases, you usually will want to use an existing pdf library.